# How to include angular components in doc.fromhtml() jspdf?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to generate a pdf which includes angular components.

**typescript:**

```
 let doc = new jsPDF();          

let source = document.getElementById("content");
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180
    });
doc.save("sample.pdf");
    }

}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="content">
    <sample-card *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index" 
      [selection] = list                  
       <sample-card>
   </div>
```

I am using Angular 4 
`doc.fromHTML()` is working for simple 'div' like To be downloaded. But its not working for angular components. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way ,
Passsing values in app html to the details, where it display those values in details html

In app.component.html

```
<div id="content" details [app1]="app" *ngFor="let app of applications">
```

In details.component.html

```
 {{app1.labels}}
```

Here i'm waiting to get the data to be loaded[Tried with AfterViewChecked -- keeps on saving files and AfterViewInit is giving null (as it is executing only once)]
So waited for Random time say 5 sec[not good but its downloading the file]

```
setTimeout(()=>{    
      setTimeout(this.saveFile(), 1000*5);
 },3000);
```

Here is the output i got[on left pdf and on right webpage with some extra content]

[image]

> For the id on top div

```
    <div id="content" >
      Things to Learn
    <div details [app1]="app" *ngFor="let app of applications">
    </div>
    Hari
    </div>
```

> Output is:

[image]

**Method-2 :**

Here i am using event emitter to tell parent when to save the file

when the child component receives the final item from the array of items [passed by parent to child] ,telling parent to save the file now [as i have received all of your items in the array]

Implemented with AfterViewInit where it emits true when length and count are same

> On left html and on right ts [of parent]

[image]

> on left ts and on right html [of child]

[image]

> Output

[image]

Comment: Adding other approach under Method-2!!

Comment: Can i post it as new one, please suggest, thanks @mxr7350